# Export unexpected Token in React and Webpack

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, ecmascript-6

I have a filename called api_path.js and within it I have this

```
export {
    api_path: 'https://localhost:3001/'
}
```

Then in my component I do

```
import { api_path } from 'config/api_path'
```

I got error:

> unexpected token, you may need an appropriate loader to handle this
>   file type.

What kind of loader do I need?

Comment: Use babel loader for ES6 modules

Comment: @Nitesh I alrdy have that.

Comment: Have you included .babelrc file ? Also, just check your webpack.config.js file(in module section), that you have added appropriate loader.

Comment: can you show your webpack file

Answer (score 0):

The [`export` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export) is not followed by an object, but a special syntax that lists the identifiers that should be exported.

You have to define a variable that you want to export.

```
const api_path = 'https://localhost:3001/'
export { api_path }
```

You can achieve the same by putting the `export` keyword before the variable declaration.

```
export const api_path = 'https://localhost:3001/'
```

There is no loader needed, because webpack 2+ handles ES modules. The error message only suggests that you may need an appropriate loader, because that wasn't valid ES module syntax but it might have been possible that you were using a special syntax on purpose and forgot to configure a loader for it (a common mistake when including another file type, like CSS).